# Customizing WordPress sumome plugin css

Tags: wordpress

I am not experienced in Wordpress and I wonder how to customize the css of the sumome plugin. I have a form for the newsletter, and would like to apply my own custom css, but not sure where should I do that, since overwriting the classes in my app.css didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a paid theme then there is option in admin "Custom CSS" and otherwise you will plase your customized css in style.css of your current  active theme.